# Spring Actuator "/actuator" endpoint not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I created a simple sample project, with only spring-web and spring-actuator. I'm not able to call the `/actuator` endpoint in this project. Only thing I get is that 404 error:

`There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available`

In the logs I can't see anything about this. I activated the `management.security.enabled=false` in the `application.properties` to avoid the security issues.

In other projects with the same spring, spring-web and spring-actuator version I reach the `/actuator` endpoint but I can't see differences.

Here is a github link to the sample project: https://github.com/ManuZiD/mzd-actuator

Any suggestions would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/actuator` requires HATEOAS to be on the classpath, which looking at your sample project it's not there, the other actuator endpoints do not require it (or have different conditional dependencies). Have you tried `/info` to verify that the other endpoints are working as expected?

To activate the `/actuator` endpoint add

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. I didn't expect that special behavior.

Comment: The health indicator endpoint has changed to /actuator/health

Comment: How the hell it's not defined in `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency?

Comment: As its optional?

Answer (score 1):

In my case `spring-boot-starter-actuator` solved the issue. I was using `spring-boot-actuator` and `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` but that wasn't working. Note the word **starter** in the package. That will be the slightest change you need to make it work.